# read Json file from url with Javascipt

Tags: javascript, openlayers

hey I couldn't find answers to this simple problem.

I'm building a simple OpenLayers project.
as part of the project I want to show all the starbucks locations on a map.

I have a URL that holds a JSON file that contains the data about all the McDonald's restaurants and I'm trying to read it in my Javascript file.

i tried :

```
    fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mmcloughlin/starbucks/master/locations.json")
  .then(response =>response.json())
  .then(json => showLocations(json));
```

but getting this error in browser console :

> VM6256:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position
> 0
> at JSON.parse ()
> at getObject (JSONFeature.js:202)
> at GeoJSON2.JSONFeature2.readFeatures (JSONFeature.js:55)
> at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (featureloader.js:106)

how can i fix that?

Comment: This is probably caused by invalid json. Please make sure the test.json file contains valid JSON.

Comment: In the browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, what is the response for this `fetch` request?

Comment: I guess the file is not found and therefore some 404 html page (starting with `<`) is returned. Can you check the status of the response (`response.status`) and if the file is reachable at this path?

Comment: I hate to tell you this but those are Starbucks locations.

Comment: If I replace showLocations with console.log your fetch works correctly.  The error message shows an unrelated error occurs in an  xhr.onload somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
fetch("./data/test.json")
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status < 300) return response.json()
    else // throw error or handle this case by giving the user an alert.
  })
  .then(json => showLocations(json));
```

This way you will only try to decode the `JSON` if you get `2XX` response.

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea to check the response status before calling .JSON() but the console message shows an unrelated JSON.parse error in OpenLayers code https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/format/JSONFeature.js#L202 following a xhr request?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you recieve a Json file?

If so try to convert the response to string and then parse it to JSON.

```
let resp = JSON.stringify(response);
res = JSON.parse(resp)
```